# Horror Manga about an (web)app that ends up killing people

Tags: story-identification, horror, manga

I read a manga about a female transfer student that befriends the most popular girl in class, a site on her phone appears and it asks which student would the person most like to die. Thinking that it was a practical joke, she votes for her "best friend", the next day a humiliating video is  posted in class.

Just before she can confront her friend, the girl dies from a hit and run accident. Traumatized, she believes that the app can kill anyone of them and the odds can be against her favor. She tries to find the culprit and learns about the truth, before her transfer there was a female teacher who had cursed their class before she committed suicide from her students mistreatment.

Answer (score 3):

**[生贄投票 (*Ikenie Touhyou*, Sacrificial Vote)](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=129404)** by KASAI Ryuuya.

[image: cover vol. 1]

> Life at the Yanagizawa private high school is boring for all attending students who prefer to stare at their smartphones for most of the day, just playing games and chatting to each other. Everyone's dormant lifestyle though seems to awaken when they are asked to vote for a classmate who will be asked to clear a task or otherwise become the "sacrifice" and suffer a "social death"! What does this mean though? Who will be the first one to be voted and what is a "social death"? The students will find out very soon that some games are far from innocent…

The description in the question is basically the 1st chapter of the 1st volume:

- the main character, a female transfer student (Minato Imabari) befriends the most popular girl in class (Kanna Iriyama)
- a malicious smartphone app called "Sacrificial Vote" appears forcefully at midnight, asking the user to vote for someone other than themself to be sacrificed. Minato does vote for Kanna.
- the next afternoon, the app appears again, announcing the vote result, the time and the cause of the death, and the condition to avoid it. It also introduces the curse of Arisa Nikaido, a female teacher who committed suicide.
- failing to fulfill the condition, a humiliating video (**NSFW scene**) of the victim is shown on the app of every student's smartphone in the middle of the class.
- shocked by the truth, the victim runs away from the class and school, gets hit by a car, then dies.

---

Note: as of current, this manga has **not been licensed** by an English publisher.